# Why does Click-to-expand javascript not work after the first content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

I'm generating `.js` file to click-to-expand the content `Full verb table`. It works well for the first `Full verb table`, whereas it does not for the second one. I've tried to figure out why, but to no avail. Could you please elaborate on how to resolve the issue?

[image]

The html file

```
aimanter
<link href="collins.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="collins.js"></script>
<div class="cB cB-def dictionary biling" data-num-block="" data-title-block="" data-type-block="aimanter" id="aimanter__1"><div class="content definitions dictionary biling"><div class="hom"><span class="gramGrp"><span class="xr"> <a class="link-right verbtable" data-text="+ " old_onclick="expandfullverbtable();" onclick="expandfullverbtable();">Full verb table</a></span><span class="hi rend-sc pos">transitive verb</span></span><div class="fullverbtable" style="display:none"><link href="collins.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><script src="collins.js" type="text/javascript"></script><div class="columns2"><div class="type"><h3>Infinitive</h3><ul><li class="infl">aimanter</li></ul></div><div class="type"><h3>Past Participle</h3><ul><li class="infl">aimanté</li></ul></div><div class="type"><h3>Gerund</h3><ul><li class="infl">aimantant</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Imperative</h3><ul><li class="infl">aimante (tu)</li><li class="infl">aimantons (nous)</li><li class="infl">aimantez (vous)</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Present</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'aimante</li><li class="infl">tu aimantes</li><li class="infl">il/elle aimante</li><li class="infl">nous aimantons</li><li class="infl">vous aimantez</li><li class="infl">ils/elles aimantent</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Present Perfect</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'ai aimanté</li><li class="infl">tu as aimanté</li><li class="infl">il/elle a aimanté</li><li class="infl">nous avons aimanté</li><li class="infl">vous avez aimanté</li><li class="infl">ils/elles ont aimanté</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Imperfect</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'aimantais</li><li class="infl">tu aimantais</li><li class="infl">il/elle aimantait</li><li class="infl">nous aimantions</li><li class="infl">vous aimantiez</li><li class="infl">ils/elles aimantaient</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Future</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'aimanterai</li><li class="infl">tu aimanteras</li><li class="infl">il/elle aimantera</li><li class="infl">nous aimanterons</li><li class="infl">vous aimanterez</li><li class="infl">ils/elles aimanteront</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Conditional</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'aimanterais</li><li class="infl">tu aimanterais</li><li class="infl">il/elle aimanterait</li><li class="infl">nous aimanterions</li><li class="infl">vous aimanteriez</li><li class="infl">ils/elles aimanteraient</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Past Historic</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'aimantai</li><li class="infl">tu aimantas</li><li class="infl">il/elle aimanta</li><li class="infl">nous aimantâmes</li><li class="infl">vous aimantâtes</li><li class="infl">ils/elles aimantèrent</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Pluperfect</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'avais aimanté</li><li class="infl">tu avais aimanté</li><li class="infl">il/elle avait aimanté</li><li class="infl">nous avions aimanté</li><li class="infl">vous aviez aimanté</li><li class="infl">ils/elles avaient aimanté</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Future Perfect</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'aurai aimanté</li><li class="infl">tu auras aimanté</li><li class="infl">il/elle aura aimanté</li><li class="infl">nous aurons aimanté</li><li class="infl">vous aurez aimanté</li><li class="infl">ils/elles auront aimanté</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Past Anterior</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'eus aimanté</li><li class="infl">tu eus aimanté</li><li class="infl">il/elle eut aimanté</li><li class="infl">nous eûmes aimanté</li><li class="infl">vous eûtes aimanté</li><li class="infl">ils/elles eurent aimanté</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Conditional Perfect</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'aurais aimanté</li><li class="infl">tu aurais aimanté</li><li class="infl">il/elle aurait aimanté</li><li class="infl">nous aurions aimanté</li><li class="infl">vous auriez aimanté</li><li class="infl">ils/elles auraient aimanté</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Present Subjunctive</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'aimante</li><li class="infl">tu aimantes</li><li class="infl">il/elle aimante</li><li class="infl">nous aimantions</li><li class="infl">vous aimantiez</li><li class="infl">ils/elles aimantent</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Imperfect Subjunctive</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'aimantasse</li><li class="infl">tu aimantasses</li><li class="infl">il/elle aimantât</li><li class="infl">nous aimantassions</li><li class="infl">vous aimantassiez</li><li class="infl">ils/elles aimantassent</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Present Perfect Subjunctive</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'aie aimanté</li><li class="infl">tu aies aimanté</li><li class="infl">il/elle ait aimanté</li><li class="infl">nous ayons aimanté</li><li class="infl">vous ayez aimanté</li><li class="infl">ils/elles aient aimanté</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Pluperfect Subjunctive</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'eusse aimanté</li><li class="infl">tu eusses aimanté</li><li class="infl">il/elle eût aimanté</li><li class="infl">nous eussions aimanté</li><li class="infl">vous eussiez aimanté</li><li class="infl">ils/elles eussent aimanté</li></ul></div></div></div></div><div class="cB-w" id="id_idm140081449779088" style="display:block"><h2 class="entry_title">Verb conjugations for aimanter</h2><div class="short_verb_table"><span class="conjugation"><span class="title">Present</span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">j'</span><span class="vb">aimante</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">tu</span><span class="vb"> aimantes</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">il/elle</span><span class="vb"> aimante</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">nous</span><span class="vb"> aimantons</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">vous</span><span class="vb"> aimantez</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">ils/elles</span><span class="vb"> aimantent</span></span></span><span class="conjugation"><span class="title">Future</span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">j'</span><span class="vb">aimanterai</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">tu</span><span class="vb"> aimanteras</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">il/elle</span><span class="vb"> aimantera</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">nous</span><span class="vb"> aimanterons</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">vous</span><span class="vb"> aimanterez</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">ils/elles</span><span class="vb"> aimanteront</span></span></span><span class="conjugation"><span class="title">Imperfect</span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">j'</span><span class="vb">aimantais</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">tu</span><span class="vb"> aimantais</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">il/elle</span><span class="vb"> aimantait</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">nous</span><span class="vb"> aimantions</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">vous</span><span class="vb"> aimantiez</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">ils/elles</span><span class="vb"> aimantaient</span></span></span><span class="conjugation"><span class="title">Present Perfect</span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">j'</span><span class="vb">ai aimanté</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">tu</span><span class="vb"> as aimanté</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">il/elle</span><span class="vb"> a aimanté</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">nous</span><span class="vb"> avons aimanté</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">vous</span><span class="vb"> avez aimanté</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">ils/elles</span><span class="vb"> ont aimanté</span></span></span></div> <a class="link-right verbtable" data-text="+" old_onclick="expandfullverbtable();" onclick="expandfullverbtable();">Full verb table</a></div></div></div>

aimer
<link href="collins.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="collins.js"></script>
<div class="cB cB-def dictionary biling" data-num-block="" data-title-block="" data-type-block="aimer" id="aimer__1"><div class="content definitions dictionary biling"><div class="hom"><span class="gramGrp"><span class="xr"> <a class="link-right verbtable" data-text="+" old_onclick="expandfullverbtable();" onclick="expandfullverbtable();">Full verb table</a></span><span class="hi rend-sc pos">transitive verb</span></span><div class="fullverbtable"><link href="collins.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><script src="collins.js" type="text/javascript"></script><div class="columns2"><div class="type"><h3>Infinitive</h3><ul><li class="infl">aimer</li></ul></div><div class="type"><h3>Past Participle</h3><ul><li class="infl">aimé</li></ul></div><div class="type"><h3>Gerund</h3><ul><li class="infl">aimant</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Imperative</h3><ul><li class="infl">aime (tu)</li><li class="infl">aimons (nous)</li><li class="infl">aimez (vous)</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Present</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'aime</li><li class="infl">tu aimes</li><li class="infl">il/elle aime</li><li class="infl">nous aimons</li><li class="infl">vous aimez</li><li class="infl">ils/elles aiment</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Present Perfect</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'ai aimé</li><li class="infl">tu as aimé</li><li class="infl">il/elle a aimé</li><li class="infl">nous avons aimé</li><li class="infl">vous avez aimé</li><li class="infl">ils/elles ont aimé</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Imperfect</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'aimais</li><li class="infl">tu aimais</li><li class="infl">il/elle aimait</li><li class="infl">nous aimions</li><li class="infl">vous aimiez</li><li class="infl">ils/elles aimaient</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Future</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'aimerai</li><li class="infl">tu aimeras</li><li class="infl">il/elle aimera</li><li class="infl">nous aimerons</li><li class="infl">vous aimerez</li><li class="infl">ils/elles aimeront</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Conditional</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'aimerais</li><li class="infl">tu aimerais</li><li class="infl">il/elle aimerait</li><li class="infl">nous aimerions</li><li class="infl">vous aimeriez</li><li class="infl">ils/elles aimeraient</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Past Historic</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'aimai</li><li class="infl">tu aimas</li><li class="infl">il/elle aima</li><li class="infl">nous aimâmes</li><li class="infl">vous aimâtes</li><li class="infl">ils/elles aimèrent</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Pluperfect</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'avais aimé</li><li class="infl">tu avais aimé</li><li class="infl">il/elle avait aimé</li><li class="infl">nous avions aimé</li><li class="infl">vous aviez aimé</li><li class="infl">ils/elles avaient aimé</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Future Perfect</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'aurai aimé</li><li class="infl">tu auras aimé</li><li class="infl">il/elle aura aimé</li><li class="infl">nous aurons aimé</li><li class="infl">vous aurez aimé</li><li class="infl">ils/elles auront aimé</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Past Anterior</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'eus aimé</li><li class="infl">tu eus aimé</li><li class="infl">il/elle eut aimé</li><li class="infl">nous eûmes aimé</li><li class="infl">vous eûtes aimé</li><li class="infl">ils/elles eurent aimé</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Conditional Perfect</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'aurais aimé</li><li class="infl">tu aurais aimé</li><li class="infl">il/elle aurait aimé</li><li class="infl">nous aurions aimé</li><li class="infl">vous auriez aimé</li><li class="infl">ils/elles auraient aimé</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Present Subjunctive</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'aime</li><li class="infl">tu aimes</li><li class="infl">il/elle aime</li><li class="infl">nous aimions</li><li class="infl">vous aimiez</li><li class="infl">ils/elles aiment</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Imperfect Subjunctive</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'aimasse</li><li class="infl">tu aimasses</li><li class="infl">il/elle aimât</li><li class="infl">nous aimassions</li><li class="infl">vous aimassiez</li><li class="infl">ils/elles aimassent</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Present Perfect Subjunctive</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'aie aimé</li><li class="infl">tu aies aimé</li><li class="infl">il/elle ait aimé</li><li class="infl">nous ayons aimé</li><li class="infl">vous ayez aimé</li><li class="infl">ils/elles aient aimé</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Pluperfect Subjunctive</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'eusse aimé</li><li class="infl">tu eusses aimé</li><li class="infl">il/elle eût aimé</li><li class="infl">nous eussions aimé</li><li class="infl">vous eussiez aimé</li><li class="infl">ils/elles eussent aimé</li></ul></div></div></div></div><span class="xr"> <span class="lbl italics">see also</span><a class="ref" href="https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/s-aimer" title="Translation of s’aimer">s’aimer</a></span><div class="cB-w" id="id_idm140081449731952"><h2 class="entry_title">Verb conjugations for aimer</h2><div class="short_verb_table"><span class="conjugation"><span class="title">Present</span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">j'</span><span class="vb">aime</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">tu</span><span class="vb"> aimes</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">il/elle</span><span class="vb"> aime</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">nous</span><span class="vb"> aimons</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">vous</span><span class="vb"> aimez</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">ils/elles</span><span class="vb"> aiment</span></span></span><span class="conjugation"><span class="title">Future</span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">j'</span><span class="vb">aimerai</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">tu</span><span class="vb"> aimeras</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">il/elle</span><span class="vb"> aimera</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">nous</span><span class="vb"> aimerons</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">vous</span><span class="vb"> aimerez</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">ils/elles</span><span class="vb"> aimeront</span></span></span><span class="conjugation"><span class="title">Imperfect</span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">j'</span><span class="vb">aimais</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">tu</span><span class="vb"> aimais</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">il/elle</span><span class="vb"> aimait</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">nous</span><span class="vb"> aimions</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">vous</span><span class="vb"> aimiez</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">ils/elles</span><span class="vb"> aimaient</span></span></span><span class="conjugation"><span class="title">Present Perfect</span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">j'</span><span class="vb">ai aimé</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">tu</span><span class="vb"> as aimé</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">il/elle</span><span class="vb"> a aimé</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">nous</span><span class="vb"> avons aimé</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">vous</span><span class="vb"> avez aimé</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">ils/elles</span><span class="vb"> ont aimé</span></span></span></div> <a class="link-right verbtable" data-text="+" old_onclick="expandfullverbtable();" onclick="expandfullverbtable();">Full verb table</a></div></div></div>
```

```js
/*JS*/

function expandfullverbtable() {
  var attr1 = document
    .getElementsByClassName("fullverbtable")[0]
    .getAttribute("style");
  if (attr1 == null || attr1 == "display:none") {
    document
      .getElementsByClassName("fullverbtable")[0]
      .setAttribute("style", "display:block");
    document
      .getElementsByClassName("cB-w")[0]
      .setAttribute("style", "display:none");
    document
      .getElementsByClassName("verbtable")[0]
      .setAttribute("data-text", "- ");
  }

  if (attr1 == "display:block") {
    document
      .getElementsByClassName("cB-w")[0]
      .setAttribute("style", "display:block");
    document
      .getElementsByClassName("fullverbtable")[0]
      .setAttribute("style", "display:none");
    document
      .getElementsByClassName("verbtable")[0]
      .setAttribute("data-text", "+ ");
  }
}
```

```css
   /*CSS*/

div.type, div.conjugation {
  min-width: 240px;
}

ul {
    padding-inline-start: 5px;
}

.share-overlay {
  display: none;
}

.type h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #E52B50;
}

.columns2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.type .infl {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.1em 0.5em;
}

.conjugation h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #9966CC;
}

.short_verb_table {
  display: flex;

}

.conjugation .infl {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.1em 0.5em;
}

.conjugation .title {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.conjugation .infl .vb {
  font-weight: 600;
}

a.link-right.verbtable {
  padding-right: 5px;
  background-color: #e5ebf3;
}

.cB-w .link-right.verbtable {
  display: none;
}

.wnv.entry_title {
  display: none;
}

.cB.cB-hook {
  display: none;
}

.content.definitions.dictionary.biling > .xr {
  display: none;
}

.hi.rend-sc.pos {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #0069B4;
}

.pos {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #0069B4;
}

.cit.type-translation.quote {
  color: #A50021;
}

.lbl.type-misc {
  color: #008000;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.gramGrp.colloc {
  color: #008000;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.share-button {
  display: none;
}

.popup-overlay {
  display: none;
}

.titleExType {
  display: none;
}

.title_frequency_container {
  float: right;
  height: 0;
}
.word-frequency-img {
  margin-left: 0.5em;
}
.word-frequency-img,
.frenquency-title .label {
  display: inline-block;
}
.word-frequency-container .level {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #f2928e;
}
.word-frequency-container .level.roundRed {
  background-color: #c12d30;
}
.word-frequency-container .level1 {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
}
.word-frequency-container .level2 {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}
.word-frequency-container .level3 {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}
.word-frequency-container .level4 {
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
}
.word-frequency-container .level5 {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
}
.word-frequency-container .round {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.example-info {
  display: none;
}

.h2_entry {

  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.copyright {
  display: none;
}

div.sense {
  margin-left: 12px;
}

.cB.cB-e .entry_title {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.cB.cB-e::before {
  content: "Example sentences";
  font-weight: 600;
}

.titleExType {
  font-weight: 600;
}


.cB.cB-e.dcCorpEx::before {
  content: "Example sentences";
  font-weight: 600;
}

.cB.cB-e.dcCorpEx {
  margin-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
  border: black solid;
}

.cB.cB-e {
  margin-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
  border: black solid;
}

.cit.type-example.cit {
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.cit.type-example.cit .quote {
  font-style: italic;
}

.credits.popup-button .author {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}
.credits.popup-button .title {
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 4px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-style: italic;
}

.mpuslot_b-container {
  display: none;
}

.fullverbtable {
  display: none;
}

.cB-h .entry_title .h2_entry {
  display: none;
}

a.link-right.verbtable::before {
  /* content: attr(data-text); */
  font-weight: 600;
}

.fullverbtable h1 {
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.fullverbtable h3 {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.fullverbtable ul {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.conjugation h3 {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.conjugation ul {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* a.audio_play_button::before {
    pointer-events: auto;
    padding-left: 5px;
    content: "1";
} */

.example_box {
  padding-top: 8px;
}

.example_box blockquote {
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  margin-right: 3px;
}
.example_box .author {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}
.example_box .title {
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 4px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-style: italic;
}

img.imageImg {
  height: 300px;
}

img.soundpng {
  padding-left: 5px;
  height: 16px;
}

.gramGrp.pos {
  color: #0069B4;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Do you *want or have* to use JS to solve your issue? As with the use of a `<input type="checkbox">` per *table* you can do this simply with a few lines of CSS.

Comment: Furthermore (but this may be due to copy pasting to the snippet), `<link>` and `<script>` for the use of loading external files into you document should be placed inside `<head></head>` only once. Not in `<body></body>` after *each Verb*.

Comment: @RenevanderLende I'm very happy if the problem can be solved with a few lines of CSS.

Comment: Ok then, just to be clear: click on 'Full verb table' means toggle visible/invisible table? And do you want to keep the table visible until the user hits 'Full verb table' of the same *Verb* again or when the user hits another 'Full verb table' of another *Verb*. This would be the difference between checkboxes (and..and..and..) and radio buttons (or..or..or..). Personally as a user I would prefer the 'checkbox' behaviour so I can compare verbs.

Comment: @RenevanderLende I want do to keep the table visible until the user hits 'Full verb table' of the same Verb again. I mean the visibility of the tables are independent of each other,

Comment: @RenevanderLende The content of `Full verb table` is hidden at first. If I click on it, it shows. With one more click, it is again hidden.

Comment: Thanks LAD, I almost have my answer ready....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any Javascript, you can use the so-called 'checkbox-hack', which basically means that you use a *hidden* HTML checkbox and (ab)use its `:checked` state to hide/show some other element(s).

Base logic:

```
/* CSS */
.toggle                            { display: none  } /* hide from view */
.toggled-element                   { display: none  } /* default hidden state */
.toggle:checked ~ .toggled-element { display: block } /* toggle visible when <label> clicked */

<!-- HTML -->
<div>
    <label for="trigger">show/hide toggled-element</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="trigger" class="toggle">
    <div class="toggled-element">hidden until user clicks</div>
</div>
```

In your case

- you will need to create a checkbox for each *verb* with a unique ID
- put a `<label>` around the trigger text 'Full verb table'
- repeat for EACH *verb*

There's a lot of CSS in your snippet, so I put my solution at the end making sure it overrides anything.
I also needed to 'tidy' the HTML to find the proper location for the checkboxes. Snippet will therefor be quite long.

Last remark: make sure to put the `<link>` and `<script>` only once in the `<head>` of your document.

Removed HTML for second *Verb*, too many characters for SO snippet...

**The snippet**

```js
/*
  NO JAVASCRIPT INVOLVED
*/
```

```css
div.type, div.conjugation {
  min-width: 240px;
}

ul {
    padding-inline-start: 5px;
}

.share-overlay {
  display: none;
}

.type h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #E52B50;
}

.columns2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.type .infl {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.1em 0.5em;
}

.conjugation h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #9966CC;
}

.short_verb_table {
  display: flex;

}

.conjugation .infl {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.1em 0.5em;
}

.conjugation .title {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.conjugation .infl .vb {
  font-weight: 600;
}

a.link-right.verbtable {
  padding-right: 5px;
  background-color: #e5ebf3;
}

.cB-w .link-right.verbtable {
  display: none;
}

.wnv.entry_title {
  display: none;
}

.cB.cB-hook {
  display: none;
}

.content.definitions.dictionary.biling > .xr {
  display: none;
}

.hi.rend-sc.pos {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #0069B4;
}

.pos {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #0069B4;
}

.cit.type-translation.quote {
  color: #A50021;
}

.lbl.type-misc {
  color: #008000;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.gramGrp.colloc {
  color: #008000;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.share-button {
  display: none;
}

.popup-overlay {
  display: none;
}

.titleExType {
  display: none;
}

.title_frequency_container {
  float: right;
  height: 0;
}
.word-frequency-img {
  margin-left: 0.5em;
}
.word-frequency-img,
.frenquency-title .label {
  display: inline-block;
}
.word-frequency-container .level {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #f2928e;
}
.word-frequency-container .level.roundRed {
  background-color: #c12d30;
}
.word-frequency-container .level1 {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
}
.word-frequency-container .level2 {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}
.word-frequency-container .level3 {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}
.word-frequency-container .level4 {
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
}
.word-frequency-container .level5 {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
}
.word-frequency-container .round {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.example-info {
  display: none;
}

.h2_entry {

  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.copyright {
  display: none;
}

div.sense {
  margin-left: 12px;
}

.cB.cB-e .entry_title {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.cB.cB-e::before {
  content: "Example sentences";
  font-weight: 600;
}

.titleExType {
  font-weight: 600;
}


.cB.cB-e.dcCorpEx::before {
  content: "Example sentences";
  font-weight: 600;
}

.cB.cB-e.dcCorpEx {
  margin-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
  border: black solid;
}

.cB.cB-e {
  margin-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
  border: black solid;
}

.cit.type-example.cit {
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.cit.type-example.cit .quote {
  font-style: italic;
}

.credits.popup-button .author {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}
.credits.popup-button .title {
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 4px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-style: italic;
}

.mpuslot_b-container {
  display: none;
}

.fullverbtable {
  display: none;
}

.cB-h .entry_title .h2_entry {
  display: none;
}

a.link-right.verbtable::before {
  /* content: attr(data-text); */
  font-weight: 600;
}

.fullverbtable h1 {
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.fullverbtable h3 {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.fullverbtable ul {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.conjugation h3 {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.conjugation ul {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* a.audio_play_button::before {
    pointer-events: auto;
    padding-left: 5px;
    content: "1";
} */

.example_box {
  padding-top: 8px;
}

.example_box blockquote {
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  margin-right: 3px;
}
.example_box .author {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}
.example_box .title {
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 4px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-style: italic;
}

img.imageImg {
  height: 300px;
}

img.soundpng {
  padding-left: 5px;
  height: 16px;
}

.gramGrp.pos {
  color: #0069B4;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.trigger, /* to hide the checkbox and for more general use */
.gone,.hidden { display:none;position:absolute;overflow:hidden;clip:rect(0 0 0 0);
                z-index:-999999;top:-999999px;margin:-1px;padding:0; border:0;
                height:1px;width:1px;min-height:0;min-width:0 }

label          { cursor: pointer }
.fullverbtable { display: none }
.trigger:checked ~ .fullverbtable { display: block }
```

```html
aimanter
    <div class="cB cB-def dictionary biling" data-num-block="" data-title-block="" data-type-block="aimanter" id="aimanter__1">
        <div class="content definitions dictionary biling">
            <div class="hom">

                <label for="cb1">
                    <span class="gramGrp"><span class="xr"> <a class="link-right verbtable" data-text="+ ">Full verb table</a></span>
                    <span class="hi rend-sc pos">transitive verb</span></span>
                </label>
                <input id="cb1" type="checkbox" class="trigger">

                <div class="fullverbtable">
                    <div class="columns2">
                        <div class="type">
                            <h3>Infinitive</h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="infl">aimanter</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="type">
                            <h3>Past Participle</h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="infl">aimanté</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="type">
                            <h3>Gerund</h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="infl">aimantant</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="conjugation">
                            <h3>Imperative</h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="infl">aimante (tu)</li>
                                <li class="infl">aimantons (nous)</li>
                                <li class="infl">aimantez (vous)</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="conjugation">
                            <h3>Present</h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="infl">j'aimante</li>
                                <li class="infl">tu aimantes</li>
                                <li class="infl">il/elle aimante</li>
                                <li class="infl">nous aimantons</li>
                                <li class="infl">vous aimantez</li>
                                <li class="infl">ils/elles aimantent</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="conjugation">
                            <h3>Present Perfect</h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="infl">j'ai aimanté</li>
                                <li class="infl">tu as aimanté</li>
                                <li class="infl">il/elle a aimanté</li>
                                <li class="infl">nous avons aimanté</li>
                                <li class="infl">vous avez aimanté</li>
                                <li class="infl">ils/elles ont aimanté</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="conjugation">
                            <h3>Imperfect</h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="infl">j'aimantais</li>
                                <li class="infl">tu aimantais</li>
                                <li class="infl">il/elle aimantait</li>
                                <li class="infl">nous aimantions</li>
                                <li class="infl">vous aimantiez</li>
                                <li class="infl">ils/elles aimantaient</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="conjugation">
                            <h3>Future</h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="infl">j'aimanterai</li>
                                <li class="infl">tu aimanteras</li>
                                <li class="infl">il/elle aimantera</li>
                                <li class="infl">nous aimanterons</li>
                                <li class="infl">vous aimanterez</li>
                                <li class="infl">ils/elles aimanteront</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="conjugation">
                            <h3>Conditional</h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="infl">j'aimanterais</li>
                                <li class="infl">tu aimanterais</li>
                                <li class="infl">il/elle aimanterait</li>
                                <li class="infl">nous aimanterions</li>
                                <li class="infl">vous aimanteriez</li>
                                <li class="infl">ils/elles aimanteraient</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="conjugation">
                            <h3>Past Historic</h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="infl">j'aimantai</li>
                                <li class="infl">tu aimantas</li>
                                <li class="infl">il/elle aimanta</li>
                                <li class="infl">nous aimantâmes</li>
                                <li class="infl">vous aimantâtes</li>
                                <li class="infl">ils/elles aimantèrent</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="conjugation">
                            <h3>Pluperfect</h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="infl">j'avais aimanté</li>
                                <li class="infl">tu avais aimanté</li>
                                <li class="infl">il/elle avait aimanté</li>
                                <li class="infl">nous avions aimanté</li>
                                <li class="infl">vous aviez aimanté</li>
                                <li class="infl">ils/elles avaient aimanté</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="conjugation">
                            <h3>Future Perfect</h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="infl">j'aurai aimanté</li>
                                <li class="infl">tu auras aimanté</li>
                                <li class="infl">il/elle aura aimanté</li>
                                <li class="infl">nous aurons aimanté</li>
                                <li class="infl">vous aurez aimanté</li>
                                <li class="infl">ils/elles auront aimanté</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="conjugation">
                            <h3>Past Anterior</h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="infl">j'eus aimanté</li>
                                <li class="infl">tu eus aimanté</li>
                                <li class="infl">il/elle eut aimanté</li>
                                <li class="infl">nous eûmes aimanté</li>
                                <li class="infl">vous eûtes aimanté</li>
                                <li class="infl">ils/elles eurent aimanté</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="conjugation">
                            <h3>Conditional Perfect</h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="infl">j'aurais aimanté</li>
                                <li class="infl">tu aurais aimanté</li>
                                <li class="infl">il/elle aurait aimanté</li>
                                <li class="infl">nous aurions aimanté</li>
                                <li class="infl">vous auriez aimanté</li>
                                <li class="infl">ils/elles auraient aimanté</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="conjugation">
                            <h3>Present Subjunctive</h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="infl">j'aimante</li>
                                <li class="infl">tu aimantes</li>
                                <li class="infl">il/elle aimante</li>
                                <li class="infl">nous aimantions</li>
                                <li class="infl">vous aimantiez</li>
                                <li class="infl">ils/elles aimantent</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="conjugation">
                            <h3>Imperfect Subjunctive</h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="infl">j'aimantasse</li>
                                <li class="infl">tu aimantasses</li>
                                <li class="infl">il/elle aimantât</li>
                                <li class="infl">nous aimantassions</li>
                                <li class="infl">vous aimantassiez</li>
                                <li class="infl">ils/elles aimantassent</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="conjugation">
                            <h3>Present Perfect Subjunctive</h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="infl">j'aie aimanté</li>
                                <li class="infl">tu aies aimanté</li>
                                <li class="infl">il/elle ait aimanté</li>
                                <li class="infl">nous ayons aimanté</li>
                                <li class="infl">vous ayez aimanté</li>
                                <li class="infl">ils/elles aient aimanté</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="conjugation">
                            <h3>Pluperfect Subjunctive</h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="infl">j'eusse aimanté</li>
                                <li class="infl">tu eusses aimanté</li>
                                <li class="infl">il/elle eût aimanté</li>
                                <li class="infl">nous eussions aimanté</li>
                                <li class="infl">vous eussiez aimanté</li>
                                <li class="infl">ils/elles eussent aimanté</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cB-w" id="id_idm140081449779088">
                <h2 class="entry_title">Verb conjugations for aimanter</h2>
                <div class="short_verb_table">
                    <span class="conjugation"><span class="title">Present</span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">j'</span><span
                            class="vb"
                        >aimante</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">tu</span><span class="vb"> aimantes</span></span><span class="infl"><span
                            class="pn"
                        >il/elle</span><span class="vb"> aimante</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">nous</span><span class="vb">
                                aimantons</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">vous</span><span class="vb"> aimantez</span></span><span class="infl"><span
                            class="pn"
                        >ils/elles</span><span class="vb"> aimantent</span></span></span><span class="conjugation"><span class="title">Future</span><span
                        class="infl"
                    ><span class="pn">j'</span><span class="vb">aimanterai</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">tu</span><span
                            class="vb"
                        > aimanteras</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">il/elle</span><span class="vb"> aimantera</span></span><span class="infl"><span
                            class="pn"
                        >nous</span><span class="vb"> aimanterons</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">vous</span><span class="vb">
                                aimanterez</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">ils/elles</span><span class="vb"> aimanteront</span></span></span><span
                        class="conjugation"
                    ><span class="title">Imperfect</span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">j'</span><span class="vb">aimantais</span></span><span
                        class="infl"
                    ><span class="pn">tu</span><span class="vb"> aimantais</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">il/elle</span><span
                            class="vb"
                        > aimantait</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">nous</span><span class="vb"> aimantions</span></span><span class="infl"><span
                            class="pn"
                        >vous</span><span class="vb"> aimantiez</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">ils/elles</span><span class="vb">
                                aimantaient</span></span></span><span class="conjugation"><span class="title">Present Perfect</span><span class="infl"><span
                            class="pn"
                        >j'</span><span class="vb">ai aimanté</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">tu</span><span class="vb"> as aimanté</span></span><span
                        class="infl"
                    ><span class="pn">il/elle</span><span class="vb"> a aimanté</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">nous</span><span
                            class="vb"
                        > avons aimanté</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">vous</span><span class="vb"> avez aimanté</span></span><span class="infl"><span
                            class="pn"
                        >ils/elles</span><span class="vb"> ont aimanté</span></span></span>
                </div>
                <a class="link-right verbtable" data-text="+" old_onclick="expandfullverbtable();" onclick="expandfullverbtable();">Full verb
                    table</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I've just successfully modify your code to achieve my goal. Thank you so much for your kindness in writing this answer!